# Is it recommended to have large number of logical partitions in cosmosdb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

If we are partitioning a container in cosmosDb sql api , is it ok to have a partition key as unique in each document. I mean each document in the container will have its own logical partition and each logical parition will have only one document, we need to query on the unique key only so only one parition/document will get hit.  Is there still any downside of such modelling related to performance /storage...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636852/implications-of-using-id-for-the-partition-key-in-cosmosdb similar question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cosmos DB SQL API as a key/value store and only reading using ReadItemAsync() there is no downside to doing this.